# How can I delay the obscuring/masking of characters in SwiftUI's SecureField so that each typed character shows for ~1sec before it's hidden?

Tags: swiftui

When using SwiftUI's [SecureField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/securefield) the user's input it obscured / masked / turned into • immediately, which makes it difficult to confirm that one has actually typed the password correctly. Several of our users have complained about this, and it seems that most people expect to see the character they typed for about a second or so before it disappears, which gives them visual confirmation that they tapped the correct letter and can now move on w/o worrying.

Is it possible to add a delay in there and show the last typed character for a moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in SwiftUI at the moment, but here's the hack we've been using in the meantime. It stacks a SecureField on top of a TextField and toggles their opacities when the user clicks on the eye (to show the text). Granted, it shows the entire String and not the last letter, but it works.

I'm sure there are open source libraries of ways to do this in UIKit that you could convert, but I'll let someone else answer that.

```
struct SecureTextFieldView: View {
        
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var showText: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextField("Password", text: $text)
                .opacity(showText ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            SecureField("Password", text: $text)
                .opacity(showText ? 0.0 : 1.0)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground).cornerRadius(10)
        )
        .overlay(
            Image(systemName: "eye.fill")
                .foregroundColor(showText ? .black : .gray)
                .padding(.trailing)
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 20, maximumDistance: 30, pressing: { (_) in
                    showText.toggle()
                }, perform: {})
            
            , alignment: .trailing
        )
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SecureTextFieldView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecureTextFieldView()
    }
}
```